# What sites will break my iframe?

Tags: javascript, search, iframe

I'm building a search site which uses iframes to display results.  I am aware that some sites will either fail to deliver their content, or 'break out' of the frame. So far I have identified twitter, facebook and NYTimes.

What other big-name frame-busters are there?

Comment: This is not a good SO question: It is open-ended, and the information could become incorrect at any given time. I would recommend to just try it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure Paypal will be one of them. You have to keep in mind that iFrames can make it appear as though the user is actually viewing the site itself, and not your own site.

Take for example if twitter allowed iframing. A malicious hacker sets up a site with twitter in an iframe, and a login box next to it. An unsuspecting user thinks they need to login to twitter, puts in their username and password, and viola! Now the hacker has their login data.

In the sense of the NYTimes it's most likely a "don't pretend this is your content" issue.

For these reasons the chances of you running into frame-busting on big name sites are fairly high.